# Spark data transformation from jsons to new table

Tags: json, apache-spark

I have a spark table what is contains lots if IDs and a json path.

```
    +----------------------+
    |    ID |     Path     |
    +----------------------+
    |    1  | "/test.json" |
    +----------------------+
```

I have to iterate through this table, parse all of the jsons, and I need to create a new table like this

```
    +----------------------------------------------+
    | ID | ParsedJson.Column1 | ParsedJson.Column2 |
    +----------------------------------------------+
    | 1  | data 1             | data2              |
    +----------------------------------------------+
```

I can parse one json. How can I parse all of the jsons and merge the data into a table like above?

Update: After this:

```
case class Media(Id: Integer, content: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)
var arrayOfFrames = jsonDF.collect.map(row => {Media(row.getInt(1), sqlContext.read.json("/mnt/" + row(5)))})
```

I have an Array[Media] now. Dataframe content is the parsed json. So my question is how can I convert this Array of Object to a DataFrame like schema above?

Comment: Sorry, I can't format the tables :(

Comment: Why is it not editable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I successed to solve this with chained maps.

```
val arrayOfFrames = filteredFramePaths.collect.map(row => { Media(
  row.getInt(1),
  sqlContext.read.json("/mnt/" + row(5))
) } ).map(a =>
  {Media(a.id, a.content.withColumn("frame", explode($"frames")).select    ($"frame.*"))}
).map(a =>
  a.content.withColumn("id", lit(a.id))
).reduce((x, y) => x.union(y))
```